# Why must the countable sets shown in this example be closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

In the book [Introductory Real Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486612260) (Kolmogorov & Fomin, English Translation by Richard Silverman Pg 95, see below)
It says:

"the sets $X_n= \{x_n, x_{n+1}, ...\}$ form a centered system of ***closed*** sets." I am not understanding why these countable sets are closed in this space.

Obviously, for any point not in $X_n$, I can construct an open set $O$ containing only a finite set of points of $X_n$, and so I can eliminate those points to construct $X_n$ to have a null intersection with $O$. But I can't do that for *every point* without obliterating the $X_n$'s.

Can anyone tell me then why these $X_n$ sets are closed?

FYI They define a limit point of a set as "every neighborhood of the point has infinite elements of the set"

[image: Page94-95]

Comment: The question in the title isn't the same question you are asking in your post. It is not always the case that a countable subset of a compact topological space is closed, as an example, take an infinite set with the indiscrete topology. And the sets $X_n$ are equal to their closure (why?), that's a possible way to show they are closed (the closure of a set is always closed).

Comment: The title has been corrected. It seems I can't edit my comment now, though. Victor, if you need more clarification on my last point, I can post a full answer.

Comment: Please do, I am not understanding why the $X_n$ equal their closure

Answer (score 3):

This is a typo. The sets $Y_n = \{ x_n, x_{n+1}, \cdots \}$ are not necessary closed, unless the space $T$ is also a $T_1$-space. As mentioned in this [errata](http://math.gmu.edu/~tlim/errata.pdf), the sets $X_n$ should be defined as $X_n = [ \{ x_n, x_{n+1}, \cdots \} ]$, i.e., the closure of the $Y_n$s.

It is the absence of any limit point that will prove $\bigcap_n X_n = \phi$ with this new definition of $X_n$s.

PS: I spent two days trying to figure this out, until the errata saved me. And then I found your question.

Comment: I looked around more. Another person has also asked this,  a year after this question.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132309/proof-of-every-compact-space-is-countable-compact

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

For every subset $A$ of a topological space, $\bar{A} = A\cup A'$, where $\bar{A}$ is the closure of $A$ and $A'$ is the set of its limit points.

Now, we suppose that $X_n$ has no limit points, then $\overline{X_n} = X_n$, and then $X_n$ is closed, since the closure of every set is closed.

EDIT: I wrote this assuming the authors of the text meant limit point as in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point), which does not seem to be the case, see the comments below this answer.

Comment: A bit of context after looking up the definitions in my copy: K&F define $x$ to be a limit point of $M$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $M$, and they define $x$ to be a contact point of $M$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $M$. Then they define the closure of $M$ to be the set of all contact points of $M$. Given these definitions, it's not clear to me that $M$ is closed if it has no limit points. (Every finite set would be closed!) These definitions should really be included in the OP's question.

Comment: That definitely changes things, I'd assumed that by limit point the authors meant what they call "contact point". The theorem still holds, of course, by taking for each $x$ a neighbourhood $N_x$ which intersects $X$ in only a finite amount of points, and then extracting a finite subcover. I don't know how the proof they give could be salvaged, though.

Comment: Yeah, it just seems wrong as written. This book is a bit notorious because its "translator", Richard Silverman, apparently introduced  numerous errors that were not in the original Russian version. Quoting from his preface, "I have not hesitated to make a number of pedagogical and mathematical improvements that occurred to me in the course of the translation." Imagine the audacity of trying to improve upon the mathematics of Kolmogorov...

Comment: Is there a better translation, I'm already a third way into it!